# Setting up a printer for Google Cloud Print while not on the same subnet

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, printing, subnet, google-cloud-print

The printer is an Epson XP 330 and the wifi hotspot is a Meraki MR18. The Meraki MR18 puts each connected device (devices connect to the same SSID) to a different subnet. That's beneficial to prevent malwares spreading through the subnet, but makes it hard to configure any wifi enabled devices (security cameras, robot vacuum, etc - I could get through the hoops so far though).

How to register that printer? In Chrome the printer is not listed under `chrome://devices/` most probably because of the separate subnets.

---

I forgot to add that I'm running a 16.04 Ubuntu flavor. I could have printed easily if I had Windows or Mac OSX. Fortunately I could set up Epson Connect through the printer's UI, but I'll have to be on the same subnet to once configure Google Cloud Print. I tried to reconfigure Meraki, but the mode for shared printers shuts down DHCP and would work with static IPs, which is not suitable for laptops. Roaming 3 didn't work either.

Comment: "That's beneficial to prevent malwares spreading through the subnet" - Unless you have configured your network specifically so one subnet can't access another subnet this woudln't be the case.  In my old configuration my gateway was in one subnet and my router was in another and my pc connected to the router could access both subnets.

Comment: Subnets can access each other. The problem is that the Chrome's machine and the printer should be on the *same* subnet. When I say `chrome://devices/` Chrome doesn't know it should also look on another subnet. Each connected device gets a separate subnet. This is the first time ever I'm trying to set up a Google Cloud Print BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some printers (for example, Canon MX490 series), you can get around the subnet limitation by browsing directly to the printer from a web browser.  If you manage to get the printer to connect to your hotspot (I authenticated to it from the printer control panel, it was a bit fussy), you should be able to figure out the printer's IP address from the hotspot configuration screen on your phone.  Next, just type the numeric IP directly into the address bar of the browser.
For my Canon MX492, I connected my computer to the hotspot, browsed to the printer from a Chrome browser on my computer, and authenticated successfully with username "ADMIN" and password "canon".  I ended up at a screen where I clicked on "Register to Google Cloud Print".  After doing that, I could successfully print.
So far, the printer has remained at the same IP address, but I'm pretty sure it's not static.  I wouldn't be surprised if I have to browse to the printer again in the future and re-register to Google Cloud Print if DHCP ends up assigning a different IP address for whatever reason.

Comment: I'm not in the subnet situation any more but your explanation sounds proper

Comment: On another note: https://www.techspot.com/news/82899-google-killing-cloud-print-cloud-based-printing-solution.html this makes me sad

Comment: Thanks for the link.  The title of the article ("Chrome OS now has native print management features so Cloud Print isn't needed") shows typical Google narrow thinking.  There are millions of people who use Cloud Print for reasons not interchangeable with Chrome OS native print management.